# How do I make sure there is no space between my webpage and the browser edge?

Tags: html, browser, margin

I have tried setting the margin attribute to 0px, but it does not work.

Comment: @Pekka, yes, but I put the margin attribute in a div-element inside the body-element, instead of in the body-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!. I set the margin for a div. That's why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set padding and margin to 0 for body tag:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```